# El precargador no funciona en la aplicación

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un comercio electrónico a partir del cual creé una aplicación de Android usando webview para ver el comercio electrónico. Para esto, hice lo siguiente:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com/")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Se abre normalmente, pero cuando incluye un precargador para aparecer solo en la versión móvil, la consola del navegador funciona, pero por la aplicación no. Mira el código:

**CSS**

```
@media(max-width:768px){

/** PRELOADER **/   
#preloader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#3600c9; /* cor do background que vai ocupar o body */
    z-index:999; /* z-index para jogar para frente e sobrepor tudo */
}
#preloader .inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* centralizar a parte interna do preload (onde fica a animação)*/
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
.bolas > div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 3px;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: animarBola;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
}
.bolas > div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-duration:0.75s ;
    animation-delay: 0;
}
.bolas > div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-duration: 0.75s ;
    animation-delay: 0.12s;
}
.bolas > div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-duration: 0.75s  ;
    animation-delay: 0.24s;
}    
@keyframes animarBola {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    }
    16% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
    33% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1; 
    } 
}
/** FIM DO PRELOADER **/
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="preloader">
        <div class="inner">
           <div class="bolas">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>                    
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#preloader .inner').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow': 'visible'});
})
//]]>
</script>
```

Creo que el problema está en Kotlin y webview.

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de mostrar el progress bar de la página, lo ideal en este caso es agregarlo desde la aplicación y controlarlo desde aquí mismo, definiendo un `WebViewClient` a tu `WebView`.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
          
          myProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE); //*Muestra progress bar
          
        }

    @Override public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);

      myProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE); //*Elimina progress bar

    }
}
```